# Cleaning up jQuery code to something better

Tags: jquery

I feel that this bit of jQuery that I've done could do with some improvement and could be made a lot cleaner. I might be wrong, but any thoughts or how it can be done?

```
jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label").addClass("active");
jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label i").hide();

jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
  if (jQuery(this).val()=='2') {
    jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label").removeClass();
    jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label i").hide();
    jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label i").show();
    jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label").addClass("active");
  } else {
    jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label").removeClass();
    jQuery("#user_type_2_wrapper label i").hide();
    jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label i").show();
    jQuery("#user_type_3_wrapper label").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Html markup is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="#user_type_2_wrapper">
  <label>
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <input type="radio" value="2" />
    label text for option 2
  </label>
  </li>
  <li id="#user_type_3_wrapper">
  <label>
    <i class="icon"></i>
    <input type="radio" value="3" />
    label text for option 3
  </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Shouldn't that `i` be hiding already since it is a child of label.

Comment: Your selectors and logic are the same except for a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically every duplicated object can be made one object. And maybe use a function so you can call it when required.

If you use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like below, you can put this code in an external *.js file. It will then run asap without stalling other http requests while loading the page. Also pass in the `jQuery` object as a parameter so you can safely use `$` instead.

The configuration (1) separation allows you to easily change things when needed. They're also grouped and give you a better overview. Compared to the other objects the `cfg` variable is the "local global" so you can use `cfg` throughout your whole script.

The window object (2) groups your functionality or component in one object. Basically one DOM object for a project is ideal imho. Allows you to access `window.ComponentName` in other files as well.

The activation (3) is under your control. For the moment it uses the common DOM ready event and basically just runs the `init()` function.

```
// @param ($): jquery version x?
(function ($) {
    // ECMA-262/5
    "use strict";

    // 1. CONFIG
    var cfg = {
        usertypetwo: "#user_type_2_wrapper",
        usertypethree: "#user_type_3_wrapper",
        radios: "input[type='radio']",
        active: "active"
    };

    // 2. OBJECT
    window.ComponentName = {
        // 2.1 initialize
        init: function () {
            this.cacheItems();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.activate();
        },

        // 2.2 cache objects you need
        cacheItems: function () {
            this.userTypeTwo = $(cfg.usertypetwo);
            this.userTypeThree = $(cfg.usertypethree);
            this.radios = $(cfg.radios);
        },

        // 2.3 bind events
        bindEvents: function () {
            var proj = this;

            proj.radios.on("change", function (i, item) {
                // below vars could be moved to cacheItems for your example
                var twoLabel = proj.userTypeTwo.find("label"),
                    twoLabelI = proj.userTypeTwo.find("label i"),
                    threeLabel = proj.userTypeThree.find("label"),
                    threeLabelI = proj.userTypeThree.find("label i");

                if (parseInt(item.val(), 10) === 2) {
                    threeLabel.removeClass();
                    threeLabelI.hide();
                    twoLabelI.show();
                    twoLabel.addClass(cfg.active);
                } else {
                    twoLabel.removeClass();
                    twoLabelI.hide();
                    threeLabelI.show();
                    threeLabel.addClass(cfg.active);
                }
            });
        },

        // 2.4 do something on activation
        activate: function () {
            this.userTypeTwo.find("label").addClass(cfg.active);
            this.userTypeThree.find("label i").hide();
        }
    };

    // 3. INITIALIZE ON DOM READY
    $(function() {
        ComponentName.init();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Haven't checked if this works, but it should ^^

This approach allows you to combine multiple components which you should run through a minifier once you publish to production environment. Hope this gives you an idea of how things are setup in a "modular" way these days.

Comment: great result, its not shorter as thought would be a smaller solution but this works lovely and written much better than mine. Many thanks for that! its great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding removing class then add `display none` in it, this will take care of show hide problem.

Also instead of `adding/removing` `toggle` the class

```
.active
{
  //other props
  display:none;
}
```